# Mocking Python class from module can't import

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing, mocking

I have a Python script that is to be placed on a remote vendor server, which then will be run, importing a module (that isn't available to me locally).

```
from onlyonremoteserver.remoteaccessonly import CustomRemoteClass


sensor = CustomRemoteClass()
    sensor.add_channel(channel_name="Status",unit="Count",value=status,is_limit_mode=True,limit_max_error=1.5,limit_max_warning=0.5)
    sensor.add_channel(channel_name="Number Of Data Nodes",unit="Count",value=output['number_of_data_nodes'])
    sensor.add_channel(channel_name="Number of Nodes",unit="Count",value=output['number_of_nodes'])
```

How am I able to mock a class I don't have access to? Is it possible to stub the known class name, add_channel func (and its params)

I was also thinking is this even the write approach, maybe I just write different running cases, and skip this section entirely if executing remotely.

Answer (score 1):

Try to patch your module. Have you seen https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.patch?

Comment: This works to *replace* the library but it does not work if the library is *missing* altogether. Get `ModuleNotFoundError`

Answer (score 0):

YES! [unittest has mocking built in](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html).

Using unit tests to develop your code is the way to go.
If you make your code do case statements or try/catch blocks to see if you're in the test environment vs deployment, you're going to get slammed by your customer.  Or, hopefully you will.  So, use their API to create a mocked class, and unittest will allow you utilize that mocked class without having to put those awful try/catch blocks in your import statements.

Comment: This is working when the original library exists but not when it is missing entirely.